# _mysql-module in Python not found

Tags: python, mysql, database, module, installation

PyCharm couldn't import the module _mysql.

What I did before:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Did I miss one step?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Answer (score 1):

There is no module _mysql for Python 3.x!